# woocommerce change url products

Tags: url, woocommerce, permalinks, product, slug

my SEO manager ask to me to change all URL of products on the website. For import products we use WP All Import and the url of product is taken from the title of the post.
How can I change the url for example from: www.my-site/product/this-is-the-product to www.my-site/product/seo-product?
I know that there is the option in Edit Product to change the permalink but I need in a massive way...

[image]

Thanks!